# Can I change my color / design in Spiral Knights?

Tags: spiral-knights

Upon character creation in Spiral Knights, you pick a design and a color.

Are these attributes forever immutable, or does there exist an in-game way to change either option (short of creating a new character entirely)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may now change your knight's personal color by shopping from [Vatel](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Vatel) in the Haven Bazaar.

They cost 50,000 crowns each. (Can you say crownsink! \o/ )

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change your design or color (yet). Hopefully there'll be a way to do so in future updates.

Comment: For the design keep in mind that you can always set a 'costume' armor different from your actual armor. That is, you can choose to appear wearing your 0 stars spiral sallet of your choice while actually having a 5 stars unusual hat pillar of doom.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it in the begging of spiral knights or you spend 50,000 crowns on the color of your body in heathen bazaar.

Comment: Hey there, welcome to the site! It's a good idea to post answers only if you have new information not previously mentioned in the answers that are already here, instead of repeating existing answers.